# how can I select a columns (not lines) containning at least 5 same patterns

Tags: bash, awk

how can I select a columns (not lines) containning at least 5 same patterns ?

I mean something like and select the column with 3 chars 'a'

```
a dog c d 
a dog c d
1 dog dog 4
a a   dog a 
z z   dog z
```

and  get ouptut as the full column like

```
dog c
dog c
dog dog
a   dog
z   dog
```

I m looking for a vertical version of grep command if you prefer... :)
I've trying to work around with awk  but without success

pattern can be on any column any lines 
I want to printout full column having at least 3 similar patterns

here in example both columns  but they can be the 2cd & 3rd as well as 21th ans 102th columns...

Comment: not clear, which pattern is same here? Please be more clear on your question add more details on same too.

Comment: `cut -d" " -f1 yourfile` or `awk '{print $1}' yourfile`. I suggest a Linux/bash walkthrough (just the first hits on google) - there are many useful things that can help your work.

Comment: I edit the question but I cannot explain more than vertical version of grep or similar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v v='a' -v n=3 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==v) c[i]++; next} 
                               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                                  if(c[i]>=n) printf "%s", $i OFS; 
                                  print ""}' file{,}

a
a
1
a
z
```

specify the value and count; double scans the file counts the occurances and prints columns that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: Thanks  I can adapt it now ... I was trying to be more complicated ... for nothing....